# Pass ssh passphrase when building with docker compose

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, ssh, ssh-agent

I have docker image files on private github repo, I am trying to build container with docker-compose.

```
services:
  node-api-a:
    build:
      context: git@github.com:BasselTurky/bluekiwiapp-repo.git#main:api-image
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

    image: node_api_image
    container_name: nodeApiA-con
    network_mode: host
```

I used

```
eval "$(ssh-agent)"
```

```
ssh-add /home/blue/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Then I entered my passphrase, now if I use `git pull origin` in bash to pull from my private repo, I don't need to enter the passphrase.

But when I use `docker-compose up -d --build` I have to enter the passphrase.

How can I get docker to use the passphrase from ssh-agent?